# Sum array values up to a certain total amount

Tags: ruby, arrays, sum

I've got an array of hashes (sorted), something like this:

```
testArray = [{price: 540, volume: 12},
            {price: 590, volume: 18},
            {price: 630, volume: 50}]
```

Now I want to calculate the mean value up to certain total volume. Let's say someone wants to buy 40 pieces and he wants it the cheapest way. It would mean an average price of (540*12+590*18+630*50)/40 money units.

My first attempt is following:

```
testArray.each do |priceHash|
    @priceArray << priceHash.fetch(:price)
    @volumeArray << priceHash.fetch(:volume)
end


def calculateMiddlePrice(priceArray, volumeArray, totalAmount)
result = 0

# Here some crazy wild magic happens

(0...volumeArray.count).inject(0) do |r, i| 

    if (volumeArray[0..i].inject(:+)) < totalAmount

        r += volumeArray[i]*priceArray[i]
    elsif volumeArray[0..i-1].inject(:+) < totalAmount && volumeArray[0..i].inject(:+) >= totalAmount 

        theRest = volumeArray[i] - (volumeArray[0..i].inject(:+) - totalAmount)
        r += theRest * priceArray[i]
    elsif volumeArray[0] > totalAmount

        r = totalAmount * priceArray[0]
    end

    result = r      
end
result
end
```

Right now I'm not even sure why it works, but it does. However this absolutely ridiculous code in my eyes.

My second thought was to cut my testArray when the total amount is achieved. The code looks better

```
testAmount = 31

def returnIndexForSlice(array, amount)
 sum = 0

 array.each_index do |index|

  p sum += array[index][:volume]
  if sum >= amount
        return index+1
  end
 end
end

testArray.slice(0,returnIndexForSlice(testArray, testAmount))
```

Still, this just doesn't feel that right, "rubyish" if you could say so. I checked almost every method for array class, played around with bsearch, however I can't figure out a really elegant way of solving my problem.

What's crossing my mind is something like that:

```
amountToCheck = 31
array.some_method.with_index {|sum, index| return index if sum >= amountToCheck}
```

But is there such method or any other way?

Comment: This question is a good candidate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I don't understand your logic here: *wants to buy 40 pieces and he wants it the cheapest way. It would mean (540*12+590*18+630*10)/50*

Comment: Well if I were to buy 40 pieces of that good, I could buy them from the third vendor (he has 50 in stock), but I would've to pay 630 for each. The cheapest vendor offers only 12 pieces of that good, meaning I can't fulfill my demand by buying only from the first. Thus, I have to mix - 12 pieces from the first, 18 pieces from the second and 10 pieces from the third vendor.

edit: it should be divided by 40, not 50! sorry for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your prices array of hashes:

```
prices = [  {price: 540, volume: 12},
            {price: 590, volume: 18},
            {price: 630, volume: 50}]
```

You can calculate your result in 2 steps.

```
def calc_price(prices, amount)
  order = prices.flat_map{|item| [item[:price]] * item[:volume] } #step 1      
  order.first(amount).reduce(:+)/amount #step 2
end
```

Step 1: Create an array with each individual item in it (if the prices aren't sorted, you have to add a `sort_by` clause). In other words, expand the prices into a numeric array containing twelve 540's, 18 590's, etc. This uses Ruby's array repetition method: `[n] * 3 = [n, n, n]`.

Step 2: Average the first n elements

Result:

```
calc_price(prices, 40)
=> 585
```

Comment: That's just...beautiful :) Thanks a lot!