# `flat_map` being slow on big arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, sum

I have:

```
testArray = [
  {price: 540, volume: 12},
  {price: 590, volume: 18},
  {price: 630, volume: 50}
]
```

I want to calculate the mean value up to certain total volume. Let's say someone wants to buy `40` pieces and he wants it the cheapest way. It would mean an average price of

```
(540 * 12 + 590 * 18 + 630 * (40-18-12)) / 40 = 585
```

money units.

I already asked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28865096), and got the answer. However, on very large arrays, this method is slow:

```
def self.calculateMiddlePrice(prices, amount)    
  @order = prices.flat_map{|item| [item[:price].to_i] * item[:volRemain].to_i }
  unless amount > @order.count
    @order[1..amount].reduce(:+) / amount
  else
    @order.reduce(:+) / @order.count
  end
end
```

I tried the lazy operator, but without any success:

```
@order = prices.lazy.flat_map{|item| [item[:price].to_i] * item[:volRemain].to_i }.force
```

It there any more efficient way to solve my initial problem?

Comment: Why are you building this massive `Array` in the first place? You relaize that `[item[:price].to_i] * item[:volRemain].to_i` is just duplicating the `item[:price]` `item[:volRemain]` number of times correct? Also your `test_Array` does not share the structure your method is expecting. Also `unless` should not use `else` [`ruby-style-guide` reference](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-else-with-unless). Finally based on your actual question I think your logic is flawed. If you want the cheapest way to buy 40 units you should deplete the units in order of price, not find the mean.

Comment: Won't help in terms of performance, but using `Array.new(number_of_items_in_new_array, duplicated_item)` would read cleaner as I was questioning myself if you were really intending to build out an array with multiple duplicate values.

Comment: @mohnstrudel Can you define "big arrays" ?

Comment: @DavidK-J The structure is almost the same as above, the real one contains additionally a name. It queries an external API, so for some items the array may contain few thousands entries.

Comment: @engineersmnky I want to find the cheapest mean price. I.e. if you have offerings: 12 units 5 usd each, 18 units 6$ each and 40 units 8$ each and you want to buy 40 units the cheapest way you get 12*5 + 18*6 + 8 * (40-12-18)
And considering your first question - it was suggested in my previous question, which I linked.

Comment: @sawa My question was edited in such way, that the original point is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commenters above have the right idea. This is a simple `reduce` operation—no need to build long arrays:

```
def calc_price(prices, volume)
  volume_remaining = volume

  total = prices.reduce(0) do |sum, item|
    if item[:volume] > volume_remaining
      break sum + item[:price] * volume_remaining
    end
    volume_remaining -= item[:volume]
    sum + item[:price] * item[:volume]
  end

  total / volume
end
```

This method iterates over the items in `prices` using `Enumerable#reduce` and keeps a running `sum`. In each iteration it checks if `item[:volume]` is greater than `volume_remaining`. If it is, then it adds `item[:price] * volume_remaining` to the running `sum` and returns it. If it's not, then it subtracts `item[:volume]` from `volume_remaining`, then adds `item[:price] * item[:volume]` to the running `sum` and goes on to the next item.

And it works, even:

```
prices = [
  { price: 540, volume: 12 },
  { price: 590, volume: 18 },
  { price: 630, volume: 50 },
]

puts calc_price(prices, 40)
# => 585
```

P.S. There are two modifications you may wish to make to this:

1. If you want fractional results (i.e. if the average isn't a whole number), change `total / volume` to `total.to_f / volume`.
2. If you want to raise an error if the volume can't be satisfied, it's a small change:

   ```
   def calc_price(prices, volume)
     volume_remaining = volume

     total = prices.reduce(0) do |sum, item|
       if item[:volume] > volume_remaining
         sum, volume_remaining = sum + item[:price] * volume_remaining, 0
         break sum
       end
       volume_remaining -= item[:volume]
       sum + item[:price] * item[:volume]
     end

     return total / value unless volume_remaining > 0
     raise "Required volume of #{volume} could not be satisfied!"
   end
   ```

   Then:

   ```
   puts calc_price(prices, 100)
   # => RuntimeError: Required volume of 100 could not be satisfied!
   ```

Comment: Thanks, it's working and fits perfectly as a method within my module. Would it be possible to explain, how this is faster? As far as i know reduce iterates through every item, which did the previous code too. Your solution however, is, indeed, faster.

Comment: The original solution works by building an array *B* of *n* items, where *n* is the sum of all volumes, i.e. if the original array (*A*) is `[ { price: 50, volume: 1 }, { price: 60, volume: 2 } ]` it will turn that into the array `[50, 60, 60]`.  So if *A* has 200 items each with a `:volume` of 500, *B* will have 100,000 items. Then it sums the first *amount* items in *B*, so if *amount* is 1,000, it does 1,000 (well, 999) additions. Both building *B* and summing the items could take a fair amount of time if your numbers are large enough.

Comment: My solution, on the other hand, doesn't build any additional arrays. It just does math. If there are 200 items in *A* it will do 200 iterations at most, and perform 199 additions at most. If *amount* is 25 and the first three items in *A* have `:volume`s 9, 10 and 8, it will perform only two additions and then stop, since 9+10+8=28.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. Didn't want to plain copy the code, but understand it too :)

Answer (score 1):

This should improve the performance a lot as done in one pass without redundant data copying:

**EDIT: updated answer after OP's comment and changes in the orig. question**

```
testArray = [   {price: 540, volume: 12},
                {price: 590, volume: 18},
                {price: 630, volume: 50}]

to_buy = 40
wp, rem = testArray.inject({wp: 0, ct: to_buy}) do |m,h|
  unless m[:ct].zero?
    delta = [h[:volume], m[:ct]].min
    m[:wp] += h[:price] * delta
    m[:ct] -= delta
  end
  m
end.values

p wp / to_buy, rem    #  585 0
```

*Folding* over a data structure with [Enumerable#inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) which `Array` mixes-in.

Comment: And where can I define the required 40 units limit?

Comment: @mohnstrudel Updated answer. Would it match now what has been asked for ?

Comment: While your code works, I find it quite hard to understand and implement into a separate method. This is why I accepted Jordan's answer.